# Getting 404 on local apt mirror, but can download the files using wget

Tags: apache2, 22.04, apt-mirror

I have a local 22.04 mirror used by a number of servers who does not have access to the internet. The jammy mirrors are working perfectly, but yesterday I was tasked with adding the Ondrej PHP PPA to the mirror as we need to install software from there on a number of machines.

The webserver for the mirror is Apache.

Adding the PPA went fine, I added the repo to the mirror list, ran apt-mirror which recognized about 280mb new packages and pulled them, afterwards I confirmed that the mirroring went OK, the packages had been added under mirror/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu.

I Chown'ed the new packages as www-data for the webserver to have permissions to serve them.

However, after adding a new line in the sources.list for the repo location the servers are getting a 404 on them when running apt-update on the clients.

Whats odd is, if i wget the same file they receive a 404 on, it succeeds.

When doing apt-update on the client and inspecting the access logs of the mirror, I see all the 404 errors, but when comparing the path it gets 404 on, to my directory structure I can see that the packages are there - yet, the mirror is sending a 404 on them.

I am aware that I will probably have to somehow get Ondrej repo key on to the servers I use as clients here, but I need to first of all be able to use the repos.

I can provide more details in regards to config, but im forced to work through Hyper-V's RDP based console and can't copy-paste out so its all in screenshots.

Can anyone help ?

[404 from Apt-update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOhoY.png)

[Succesful retrieval from wget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg8c8.png)

[Apache conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bETH.png)

[Directory structure on mirror server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S325l.png)

[Mirror.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFvW7.png)

[Sources.list on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2PU6.png)

Comment: The 404 is send as you use `ppa.launchpad.net` instead of `ppa.lanchpadcontent.net` in your path.

Comment: oh my effing god.. thank you.. i have been staring myself blind at this!!!..... Even had a colleague look and he didn't spot this either..

Feel smart now.....

Comment: @dummyuser consider posting that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now as official Answer:
The 404 is send as you use `ppa.launchpad.net` instead of `ppa.launchpadcontent.net` in your path.